# Visual Studio will not show my .ico for project icon

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, .ico

I've tried and scouted around for a fix but I'm surprised by the lack of info out there. This process should be so simple and easy to implement, just changing the solution's icon to an acceptable-format icon.

However, I have tried to create my own icon and VS 2015 accepts that it is the correct size/format (I don't get error that states "Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as an icon." but the icon in the top left corner of my winforms stays that awful default picture icon (not the 3 red/blue/yellow computer screen mind you, but the stupid broken page/form icon?), and on my task bar it stays the same, even though I've gone through project-->properties-->application--> and included my proper .ico with the correct location. I've also changed the Icon in the winforms property tab to be the same .ico file to no avail.

I've also tried to clean/rebuild solution, restart/reinstall VS 2015 comm and nothing.

Does anyone know what's going on with this? I've put this part of my project off as long as I could as it is just a cosmetic attribute really, but it's driving me nuts something so simple is too complicated or broken. I couldn't find specific information about the dimensions needed for .ico icon in my solution, but I know it's 32x32 pixels, and I've created all the variations of a 32x32 .ico in the visual studio paint editor. Visual Studio does not display a single one of them, just the broken blank page icon instead.

Just want stupid thing to display the right icon >.>
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to display the picture and any related to it code that you consider important for this matter?

Comment: I wasn't aware I had to programmatically set the icon, I have set the icon in the form properties tab, as well as assigned the .ico file as the Icon in the tab "Project--->properties--->application--->Icon and Manifest".

Is it redundantly necessary to set the .ico file as the Icon for my form programmatically as well as in all of these settings windows? seems outrageous to need to do all of this for just an application icon...

Comment: Solved it, thanks all. I added from NuGet Inedo.Iconator and reset my icon in the form properties tab. Works like a charm. Not sure what the issue was but it's fixed now and I hope my answer helps others with this issue.